# How do I change a complete HTML from input to image and mantain onClick events

Tags: jquery, html

I need to change this HTML from this:

```
<input type="button" class="rsform-button" id="compra_exc" name="form[compra_exc]" value="Buy">
```

To this:

```
<img src="button_ok" class="rsform-button" id="compra_exc" name="form[compra_exc]" />
```

But I need to maintain button behavior meaning when I click the button the form should be send, maybe getting form name and writing this:

```
$("#compra_exc").click(function(){
 $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

Did the job not so sure (hope yours tell me if I'm right or not) but I don't know how to change the HTML code, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to change from input to img?  Couldn't you give your input a background-image?  You may have to adjust the width and height to fit that of your image, but you could make it look exactly the same, without having to manipulate the dom.

```
.rsform-button {
    background-image: url('button_ok.png');
}
```

Comment: you're right, didn't think on that path and got the hard and complex, thanks I try with this one before get into change HTML markup unnecessarily

Comment: also, keep in mind that input's are `display:inline`, you might want to add `display:block` to the `.rsform-button` class if you're having problems getting the css right.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to click on a new element you cannot call the element directly, so you can call the form and find the id under it:

```
var content='<img src="button_ok" class="rsform-button" id="compra_exc" name="form[compra_exc]" />'
$('#compra_exc').after(content);
$('input[id=compra_exc]').remove();
$("#form_id").find('#compra_exc').click(function () {
   $("#form_id").submit();
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/YJRTj/)**

Comment: this should work with form submission but what about the change from input to img?

Comment: this is the markup (html structure) so I get lost about what yo said before

Comment: @Reynier, just added demo also.